# Space filling curves: Hilbert vs Peano

Tags: continuity, compactness, curves

It seems that  both the Peano's and Hilbert's space filling curve are same in nature. What is the basic difference between them?

Comment: Do you know how the two curves are defined?

Comment: I know their construction. I don't know their exact definition

Comment: What *means* "same in nature"?